# Are there intentional similarities between the lighthouse and the dark tower, from "BioShock Infinite" and "Dark Tower" series?

Tags: video-games, the-dark-tower, bioshock

Has anyone completed *BioShock Infinite* and the entire *Dark Tower* series? Has anyone read into the many similarities as how the dark tower and the lighthouse serve as linchpins to connecting many universes?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking here. Did _you_ notice any similarities? What were they? Would you like a confirmation that those similarities were intentional? I tried to edit your title to make it more of a question, but the body of your post could use more clarification, otherwise, I'm afraid, it might get closed as being primarily opinion-based. Take the [tour] and see the [ask] page to learn what type of questions are on-topic here.

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but I see a big difference. The Tower was literally the linchpin holding reality together. The lighthouse didn't seem to serve such a vital function. I doubt if you destroyed all the lighthouses that reality would end.

Answer (score 2):

There are some similarities, and other people have made the connection too, as you can see by googling.

However, while [*BioShock*'s Creative Director Ken Levine is an "old school King fan", he never got into *The Dark Tower*](https://twitter.com/levine/status/316245892648816640), so any similarities are probably unintentional.

[Levine does say in an interview](https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2011/07/07/bioshock-infinite-gillen-vs-levine/#more-65407) that Stephen King's non-fiction book *On Writing* was an inspiration on how he wrote the game's story:

> Gillen: I suppose what I was getting at was what books should people read if they want to follow your thinking?
>   Levine: Have you read Stephen King’s book On Writing?

He might have been aware of the ending to *The Dark Tower* through his love for King, but it doesn't seem to have been direct.